# Windows AD OU Block (Read/List) Objects from other OU

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

I have a Root OU that has an OU called "Clients" and under I have multiple OU's and the client's PC's/User Accounts in sub-OU's.

The issue is, my clients can see other groups' user accounts/computers and need to prevent this as if they're on completely different machines and not under the same Domain. I am guessing I have to go make Deny rules for every single OU Group about every Client OU Group?

Currently, they can search AD for users and see other clients (not within a said company).

Any thoughts on how to do it and potentially with Powershell or just in general?

Comment: Is there a reason that multiple AD Forests is not considered appropriate when handling accounts from different entities?

Comment: This sounds like a disaster waiting to happen. Are these clients separate business and legal entities? If so, I wouldn't want to be anywhere near this situation.

Comment: So, we're creating multiple AD Forests but right now, I need a quick fix as I can't just take them fully offline, and trying to coordinate with nine companies at once anytime soon, is not happening.

I've already had to hide the Users folders with ACL permissions, I know I currently have to add the groups of others OU into the said group and create a DENY permission. But I was hoping for a better temp solution and I inherited this mess and did not create it.

As for if they're separate entities, not sure how that helps the conversation, obviously not ideal & why I am looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just created new SG's and added existing SG's into it and attached them to the Top-level OU.